# Broadcast receiver startActivity with singleTop

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

I listen the GPS activation or the GPS deactivation with a broadcast receiver subscribe to **android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED**.

When the GPS is deactivate, I would like print a popup. To do that, I use the following code :

```
public class GPSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public GPSReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean gps = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean network = manager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!gps || !network) {

        Intent popup = new Intent(context,
                ModalActivity.class);
        popup.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(popup);
    }
}
```

My popup is printing all right. But I have 2 popup. In fact, when i cut the GPS my OnReceive is called 2 times : for the network and for the GPS.

How can i print only one popup ?

I try many solutions :

1) I try to start my activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP but I have this error :

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

2) I try to call my activity with NEW_TASK and SINGLE_TOP flagbut I have 2 popup :

```
popup.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
popup.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

3) I try to add a public static boolean to know if my activity was started but my onReceive seem to be call at the same time. So my boolean was modify after onReceive called.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following setup worked for me.

Set the activity as singleTask in your manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

And then call it with these flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```